# How to increase number of recent files in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to increase the number of recent files that appear in the File -> Open recent menu in Sublime Text 3 (Ubuntu)?

I have already read [Increase number of recent projects in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769156/increase-number-of-recent-projects-in-sublime-text-2)

And I can't find this ~/Library folder at my PC. I can find ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages but there's no "Default" subfolder inside.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Default package in Sublime Text 3 on Linux is stored in (assuming you used the .deb installer) `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package`.

`Default.sublime-package` is a ZIP file, if you open it and extract the `Main.sublime-menu` file from it into `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`, it can then be edited the same way as the linked answer describes.

Alternatively run following commands which will create the Default directory and extract the `Main.sublime-menu` file into it:

```
mkdir ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/
unzip -p /opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package Main.sublime-menu > ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu
```

Comment: to edit: sudo gedit .config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu. FIND: "caption": "Open Recent",                 "mnemonic": "R", "children": JUST ADD MORE LINES

Comment: On Windows: Open `%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`, add `Default` directory.  Paste the edited Main.sublime-menu as described in the answer.  (Yes, you can paste DOS env vars into file Explorer bar and Run... box.)

Answer (score 81):

On OSX, at least, the Default.sublime-package is in the application itself: `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package`.

To edit the config easily without changes being overwritten on update, you need a copy of  Main.sublime-menu in your Packages directory `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`

The easiest way to effect these changes is to install the excellent [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) by skuroda (using Package Control), then:

1. Command+Shift+p
2. type 'resource' and select '**PackageResourceViewer: Open resource**'
3. you see a list of available packages: select '**Default**'
4. select '**Main.sublime-menu**'
5. PackageResourceViewer now copies `Main.sublime-menu` into the correct location and opens the new file for editing (note: the file doesn't seem to be actually created in the filesystem until hitting save, and updates seem immediately visible without requiring an update).
6. As per Rufus_12's answer, alter the number of `open_recent_folder` and `open_recent_file` statements that appear, increasing the index each time.

   ```
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 0 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 1 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 2 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 3 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 4 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 5 } },
   { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 6 } },
   ...continue as many times as necessary...
   ```

#### Update re: maintainability

As @drevicko points out, this method will not auto-update with Sublime, and may even cause conflicts in future.

[@James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34512015/2586761) (editing the Packages/User/Default/Main.sublime-menus) is indeed update-proof, but does, unfortunately, result in a duplicate sub-menu (the duplicate entries appear for me at the very bottom of the menu). The user settings file is merged with the defaults, but in a manner which results in duplicate keys.

I find that if I update Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menus, then that file completely replaces the default (delete chunks and see your menus disappear in real time!) - my new file and the defaults are not merged.

In order to: a) avoid a duplicate entry, and b) stay current with Sublime updates, I can't see an alternative to tracking changes to the file using git, and when Sublime updates, repeating the `Open Resource` process (overwriting your edits), then reverting only relevant changes.

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.

Comment: Usefull and easy with PackageResourceViewer. ty

Comment: I like that this uses Sublime to solve its own problem.

Comment: This also works for the Recent Files in the Project menu. Look for the "Project" section in Main.sublime-menu.

Comment: For those wanting to increase the number of recent projects, the follow the same instructions as above, but with `{ "command": "open_recent_project_or_workspace", "args": {"index": 0 } },` - in the same Main.sublime-menu (thanks @chuckf)

Comment: If PackageResourceViewer is not installed go to Command Palette Command + Shift + p, enter Package Control: Install Package then search for PackageResourceViewer. (from http://vvvio.com/increase-the-number-of-recent-files-or-folders-in-sublime-text-3/)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: With most packages, the "User" version of the config file usually only has the options you want to change from the default, allowing others to be changed on updates. This looks like it creates a complete copy.. What happens if something is changed in an update?? Presumably it's still overridden by our new version of Main.sublime-menu??

Comment: There was no PackageResourceViewer option in drop down. Is this answer obsolete?

Comment: > "install the excellent PackageResourceViewer by skuroda"; haven't reviewed the steps recently, but the package format looks familiar, reckon it will still work YOLO!

Comment: > "This looks like it creates a complete copy." Yup - see the footnote in the answer. Seems the extracted package needs to include all the settings, otherwise other mens / items disappear ><

Answer (score 19):

Add this `Main.sublime-menu` to your `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` folder. You will see an added **File** Menu child named **Open Recent More**, giving you the next same-amount of recent files/folders. (If only I could position it in the menu where I want it, though.)

```
[
    {
        "caption": "File",
        "mnemonic": "F",
        "id": "file",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "caption": "Open Recent More",
                "mnemonic": "R",
                "children":
                [
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                    { "caption": "-" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't replace the default Open Recent menu, but at least this solution doesn't make me hate myself. Honestly, this should be the default suggestion for anyone desiring this functionality.

Comment: Works great! I added it as a symbolic link to the actual file I keep in Dropbox. My way to make it "upgrade proof" to some degree, at least if I upgrade my machine and need to reinstall Sublime.

Answer (score 10):

For those of you who are too lazy to copy and paste then change the numbers, here is 50 of them.

```
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 0 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 1 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 2 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 3 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 4 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 5 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 6 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 7 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 17 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 18 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 19 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 20 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 21 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 22 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 23 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 24 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 25 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 26 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 27 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 28 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 29 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 30 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 31 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 32 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 33 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 34 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 35 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 36 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 37 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 38 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 39 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 40 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 41 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 42 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 43 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 44 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 45 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 46 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 47 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 48 } },
                { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 49 } },
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 7 or 8 you:

1. Open the following file in a ZIP/archive utility:
   `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default.sublime-package`
2. Extract only the file `Main.sublime-menu` into:
   `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default`
   (Create the folder if necessary)

   The folder is otherwise known as:
   `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default`
3. Open `Main.sublime-menu` (a JSON file) that you just extracted and alter the number of `open_recent_folder` and `open_recent_file` statements that appear, increasing the index each time.

   ```
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 0 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 1 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 2 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 3 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 4 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 5 } },
       { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 6 } },
       ...continue as many times as necessary...
   ```
4. Hit save and the menu should be instantly updated.  :-)

You can even move your recent file/folder list into the root "File" menu for easier access.

Answer (score 5):

**I found you don't actually need to override the main menu**;
just add your own menu which will appear in the end.

**Create this new file** (path for me in linux, in Sublime Text 3):
`~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Main.sublime-menu`

In that file put something similar to OdatNurd previous answer;

(and I copy paste the same content into the files:
`Context.sublime-menu`
`Side Bar.sublime-menu`
to have the same submenu show up there)

---

I just made my own submenu from my own initials "elm" and put all stuff I personally use there with various "children" subtrees.

As a bonus, **it will automatically show keyboard shortcuts to the same command behind it**,
so I also use it as a reminder for actions that I don't use very often and forget the keyboard shortcut of.

---

**This works for Sublime Text 3**,
but perhaps someone can test if this also works for Sublime Text 2?

---

My file looks something like this:
(also added some more ideas (beside plenty recent files) for inspiration)

```
[
    {
        "caption" : "elm",
        "mnemonic": "M",
        "children": [
            {
                "caption": "Open Recent",
                "mnemonic": "R",
                "children": [
                    { "command": "reopen_last_file", "caption": "Reopen Closed File" },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 0 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 1 } },
                    // ... etc.
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 29 } },
                ],
            },
            {
                "caption": "Multi Line/Caret editing",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "caption": "split_selection_into_lines",
                        "command": "split_selection_into_lines",
                    },
                    {
                        "caption": "Add caret above (select_lines)",
                        "command": "select_lines",
                        "args": {"forward": false},
                    },
                    {
                        "caption": "Add caret below (select_lines)",
                        "command": "select_lines",
                        "args": {"forward": true},
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "caption": "Bookmarks",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "caption": "toggle_bookmark",
                        "command": "toggle_bookmark",
                    },
                    {
                        "caption": "prev_bookmark",
                        "command": "prev_bookmark",
                    },
                    {
                        "caption": "next_bookmark",
                        "command": "next_bookmark",
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "caption": "paste_from_history",
                "command": "paste_from_history",
            },
            {
                "caption": "Jump to matching bracket",
                "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "brackets"},
            },
            // ... etc. etc.
        ],
    },
]
```

---

Bit off topic for just more recent files, but I thought this approach might also improve other usability and maintainability aspects at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

I have come recently to need these edition open files/folders.
However, the catch is that I did not want to over-fill the main menu.  I have created a submenu item which shows the other files/folders.

In addtion to above excelent answers from @ptim and @MoonLite, I have created a submenus which prevents overcrowding it with numerous entries.  On windows the path is (when using custom `scoop` directory: `C:\app_scoop\apps\sublime-text\current\Data\Packages\Default`).

I have found out that you can acutally overload the menu.  Just copy out the `Main.sublime-menu`;  modify it with below code and place it into `C:\app_scoop\apps\sublime-text\current\Data\Packages\Default` and you will have custom menu with submenus.

I'm sharing a submenu way to view the files/folders (using Directories instead of Folders to have easier shortcut F... Files,  D ... directories):

```
 {
        "caption": "File",
        "mnemonic": "F",
        "id": "file",
        "children":
        [
            { "command": "new_file", "caption": "New File", "mnemonic": "N" },

            { "command": "prompt_open_file", "caption": "Open File…", "mnemonic": "O", "platform": "!OSX" },
            { "command": "prompt_open_folder", "caption": "Open Folder…", "platform": "!OSX" },
            { "command": "prompt_open", "caption": "Open…", "platform": "OSX" },
            {
                "caption": "Open Recent",
                "mnemonic": "R",
                "children":
                [
                    { "command": "reopen_last_file", "caption": "Reopen Closed File" },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 0 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 1 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 2 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 3 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 4 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 5 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 6 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 7 } },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "caption": "More Recent Files",
                      "mnemonic": "F",
                      "children":
                      [
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 17 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 18 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 19 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_file", "args": {"index": 20 } },
                      ]
                    },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 0 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 1 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 2 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 3 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 4 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 5 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 6 } },
                    { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 7 } },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "caption": "More Recent Directories",
                      "mnemonic": "D",
                      "children":
                      [
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 8 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 9 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 10 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 11 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 12 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 13 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 14 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 15 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 16 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 17 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 18 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 19 } },
                        { "command": "open_recent_folder", "args": {"index": 20 } },
                      ]
                    },
                    { "caption": "-" },
                    { "command": "clear_recent_files", "caption": "Clear Items" }
                ]
            },

... (continued)
```